# Component call does not display value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-component

I am building a picker with data taken from a database. It works fine, but I can't send the value I have stored in `auth.token` (in the `useAuth` component) to the URL. I have tried in many ways and I am not able, can you tell me how I can?

```js
//Call
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";

const ValorToken = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const valorToken = auth.token;
  return (valorToken)
};

export default class Cias extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://url-test-test.es/api_movil/test.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ValorToken}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: ValorToken,
        id_marca: '5'
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
      }, function() {});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, useAuth is a react hook that depends on react core hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`, ...) so it should get called only in a function component.

Here is another implementation if you want this kind of behavior (getting value from a react hook in a class component

```js
import React from 'react';

class Cias extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {valorToken} = this.props;
    return fetch('https://url-test-test.es/api_movil/test.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${valorToken}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: valorToken,
        id_marca: '5',
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson,
          },
          function () {},
        );
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}

const CiasWrapper = () => {
  const {auth} = useAuth();

  return <Cias valorToken={auth.token} />;
};

export default CiasWrapper;
```

but as a best practice, you should use functional components for hooks, you can implement the same behavior with a function component like

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const Cias = () => {
  const {auth} = useAuth();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://url-test-test.es/api_movil/test.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: auth.token,
        id_marca: '5',
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setDataSource(responseJson);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <View />;
};

export default Cias;
```

you can read more about function components and hooks at [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)